# How do I show the message "No Products" when there's no products in my custom block?

Tags: magento-1.9, blocks, cms, frontend, phtml

I need to show the message "No Products" or "There are no products matching the selection" when there's nothing to show in my block.

```
<?php        
$manufacturer = Mage::registry('current_product')->getMerchantName();

$productCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
->addAttributeToSelect('*')
->addAttributeToFilter('merchant_name',$manufacturer);
$productCollection->getSelect()->order('RAND()');
$productCollection->getSelect()->limit(5);

foreach ($productCollection as $_product)
?>

<a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_product->getName()) ?>" class="product-image"><img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'thumbnail')->resize(228) ?>" width="228" height="228" alt="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_product->getName()) ?>" /></a>

<div class="product-details">
<p class="product-name"><a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>"><?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_product->getName()) ?></a></p>

<?php   
$merchant_name = $_product->getAttributeText('merchant_name');
if ($merchant_name){?>
<div>by <?php echo $merchant_name;?> </div>
<?php }

else if ($_product->getIsEbayaffiliate()) { ?>
<div>by eBay</div>
<?php }

else { ?>
<div>by Home Done</div>
<?php } ?>
```

Also I need to add getPriceHtml to the above code to show the product price.

I have tried `<?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_item, true) ?>` this but price remains blank.

Comment: Can you please share full code of phtml?

Comment: I have already shown the full code here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Use `getSize()` function  for checking collection size.**

SO before foreach loop use

```
if($productCollection->getSize()>0){
foreach ($productCollection as $_product):
..
...
endforeach;
}else{
echo "There are no products matching the selection";
}
```

For use,$this->getPriceHtml($_product, true),custom phtml  block class `should  need to extends Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Abstract` then  `$this->getPriceHtml($_product, true);` will be workss

**Example:**

```
class YoumoduleNamespace_yourModuleName_Block_yourclass extends Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Abstract
```

.

**Edit**

```
<?php        
    $manufacturer = Mage::registry('current_product')->getMerchantName();

    $productCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
                         ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                         ->addAttributeToFilter('merchant_name',$manufacturer);
    $productCollection->getSelect()->order('RAND()');
    $productCollection->getSelect()->limit(5);

    if($productCollection->getSize()>0){
    foreach ($productCollection as $_product):
 ?>
<a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_product->getName()) ?>" class="product-image"><img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'thumbnail')->resize(228) ?>" width="228" height="228" alt="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_product->getName()) ?>" /></a>
<div class="product-details">
                        <p class="product-name"><a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>"><?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_product->getName()) ?></a></p>

    <?php  
    $merchant_name = $_product->getAttributeText('merchant_name');
     if ($merchant_name){?>
          <div>by <?php echo $merchant_name;?> </div>
    <?php }

    elseif($_product->getIsEbayaffiliate()) { ?>
            <div>by eBay</div>
          <?php }

    else { ?>
    <div>by Home Done</div>
    <?php } ?>
<?php   
endforeach;
}else{
echo "There are no products matching the selection";
}
?>
```

Comment: I am getting the error "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in catalog/product/list/random.phtml on line 37". Here is the random.phtml code https://jsfiddle.net/a67cedan/

Comment: put ur code at http://pastebin.com/

Comment: here it is http://pastebin.com/8UG0NDG0

Comment: you have doing phpsyntax,please use any php editor

Comment: Do I need to edit my static block to call product price? I couldn't get that you explained above regarding the price.